# Java heap over flow in restlet client

Tags: java, restlet, heap-memory

Maybe my doubt is a bit silly. But I couldn't find any answer similar with my problem. But after some time requests (about 20 invocations of this method), the client get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

the client is:

```
final ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(host + userInteracId);
try {
    Client httpClient = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
    httpClient.setConnectTimeout(36000);
    cr.setNext(httpClient);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JsonRepresentation jr = new JsonRepresentation(obj);
    cr.put(jr);
    jr.release();

    cr.setNext(httpClient);
    Representation r = cr.get();
    result = new JsonRepresentation(r).getJsonObject();
    r.release();
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = new JSONObject();
} finally {
    cr.release();
    cr.getResponseEntity().release();
}
```

and the Exception is:

```
WARNING: Unexpected error while controlling connector
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:39)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:312)
at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.createByteBuffer(Buffer.java:64)
at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:125)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.<init>(Way.java:97)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.OutboundWay.<init>(OutboundWay.java:105)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.ClientOutboundWay.<init>(ClientOutboundWay.java:59)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpClientOutboundWay.<init>(HttpClientOutboundWay.java:59)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpClientHelper.createOutboundWay(HttpClientHelper.java:63)
at org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:128)
```

...

Comment: Do you have to release the result that is returned by this code?

Comment: I would try Eclipse Memory Analyzer, watch the heap and see what kind of classes fill up your heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an exception is raised before the jr.release() or the r.release(), those methods will never get called. The only release() called in the finally block is for cr, not jr or r.

I recommend putting some logging in the catch block to see if an exception is being thrown.